# Using Regex I want to keep some special characters but remove another (vertical bar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, input

Im trying to exclude the vertical bar '|' from my input field called Comments, although i still want to keep basic punctuation like , . : ; - im getting stuck on how to keep some special characters but remove another. In not strong with Regular Expression, hoping some fresh eyes will help.

This is what Ive got so far;

```
$('#comments').keydown(function (e) {

  var k = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

  if (k.match(/[^a-z A-Z0-9\x08]/g))
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works. I have no idea why the code for the pipe character is `220` and not `124`, but there you go!

```js
var $comments = $('#comments');

var pipeKeycode = 220; // I cannot figure out why

$comments.on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which === pipeKeycode) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Comments: <input id="comments"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent user from typing `|`.
I don't prevent user from pasting a string with `|`, but after user gets out of the field, I remove that character in `blur`:

```js
$('#comments').keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.key === '|')
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('#comments').blur(function (e) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/\|/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="comments">
```

Comment: It would be more useful to turn this into a runnable snippet so we can play with it and test it out. Also, the support for the `key` property is not universal: https://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key

Comment: I have added the snippet. As for `key`, it's not fully universal, but popular enough. IE 11 is not supported anymore by Microsoft, the only problem is with Opera Mini and Android Browser. But neither is within the most popular 2% ;).